# Grails: Generate SQL CREATE TABLE statements from domain classes

Tags: mysql, grails

Grails can automatically create database tables (e.g. in MySQL) based on domain classes.

During debugging, is there a command that will simply print out the SQL statement that would be executed against the database to create the table, based on a domain class?

That is, instead of having Grails actually trying to create the table and generate potential errors (yes, that may include the CREATE TABLE statement).

I would find it useful sometimes to have Grails tell me what SQL CREATE TABLE statement it thinks a domain class maps to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [schema-export](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/schema-export.html) command for this.

If you're using Grails 3 you'll need to add the plugin as a `classpath` dependency in `buildscript.dependencies`. This is done for you in recent Grails 3 versions but in an earlier release you just need to add it yourself:

```
buildscript {
   ...
   dependencies {        
      ...
      classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate:4.3.10.5"
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it would be nice to be able to do it on a per-domain-class basis. But I can always pipe to "grep".